# How Ethernet receives the bits and forms the Data Link Layer Frame

Tags: networking, ethernet, osi

I am curious to know how the incoming bits at the physical layer are properly framed and sent to the data link layer. How the OS deal with this process.

It would be grateful if you explained it in detail or give me some links/pdf.

I am interested to know in depth about Layer 1 and 2 operations.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: Adriano Sorry for that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The physical layer depends on your hardware.  You're probably connected via ethernet, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet). The operating system doesn't do a lot here, it's mostly left up to the network card and the device drivers written by the card's manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

The good thing about today, is you seldom have to remember anything but Google.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet

However, the question is NOT about the physical layer as that is really the wires and interfaces for the wires; hence physical connections. His questions addresses the [Data-Link layer in OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) terms.

As Ethernet Does not match the OSI model and the fact that the OSI model is a strategic rather than a tactical model, in Ethernet terms you are interested in the [802.3 MAC Frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.3). But then as Ethernet is old, there are actually a several of different [EtherTypes](http://www.networkdictionary.com/networking/EtherType.php).

Comment: Have a look at what jeemster posted, especially at "802.3 MAC Frame" part....
Preamble, Start-of-Frame-Delimiter, Interframe gap and Payload are what tell the story...

Answer (score -3):

For sharing the data, some protocol is needed as human .so here 7 layers are given .
Physical layer direct connect with the hardware( when pulse sends in Bit format ).
It deals with mechanical and electrical specification of the interface and transmission medium. 
OS have only authority to run the application not any participation in any software .
If you want detail then better read SIGNAL AND SYSTEM.